# How to automatically remember the last path where I was? [*nix]

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, remote-access

Is there any scripts or tools that can automatically remember and write down the path I am?
I asked because, when I was remote accessing my campus cluster via ssh last night, they will log me out every eight hours if I did nothing. I hope when I log in back again this morning, I would be in the folder where I was last night. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) tool (to create a session do: `screen -S myscreen`) and have the session alive even if you are forced to disconnect. So when you login next time, you can do `screen -r` or `screen -x` to connect back to your session.

Unless you reboot the system or exit manually, the screen session will be active.

Answer (score 3):

If the server has [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), use it. Also, there are sometimes environment variables that can be set or unset to prevent automatic logouts, depending on how your server is setup. I am in a tcsh and have this in my ~/.cshrc:

```
unset autologout
```